# Multiple OS X images on one USB key

Tags: macos

I have an OS X 10.6 install copied onto a 16 GB USB key that has a single partition.

I now want to upgrade to 10.8 and keep a copy. I've never used the Mac App Store before, so my first question is: when I buy do I simply get to download the installer?

My main question is: can I easily add the 10.8 installer on my key or does each installer have to have its own partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you want bootable installer, it has to be on a separate partition. If you want to do that follow "[How to create an OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion install drive](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57479690-263/how-to-create-an-os-x-10.8-mountain-lion-install-drive/)".

If you don't need a bootable installer, you can just copy the `Install Mac OS X Mountain Lion.app`, mentioned at step 2 to any drive you want, including the existing 10.6 install drive, but the result won't be a bootable 10.8 installer. However, you can still install 10.8 by running that file from within 10.6.

Comment: Am I likely to be able to take my existing USB stick with 10.6, and re-partition it without losing 10.6, ideally so the existing partition shrinks to the minimum size needed?

Comment: You should be able to repartition the USB drive without losing data, see this: http://pondini.org/OSX/DU4.html. But as always, have a backup of the data before doing anything fancy with Disk Utility.